# Im basically trying to run a simulation loop where I subtract a living expenses from my my savings account amount

Tags: r

I'm trying to run a simulation where I subtract 30,000$ in living expenses from my 1,000,000 $ savings account every year for 50 years. I want the 30,000$ in living expenses to increase every year by 5%(inflation) but I'm not sure how to do that. Here's what I have so far.

```
#set parameters
living.expense = 30000
years = 50
account.value = 1000000
num.replicates = 1000

#create storage vector
account.value = vector("numeric", num.replicates)

#set seed
set.seed(2019)

#simulate returns
for(i in 1:num.replicates){

  for(k in 1:years){
    #what is living expense
    living.expensethisyear=living.expense*(1 + 0.05)^((k) - 1) 
    #take out living expenses at beginning of year
    account.value[i] = account.value[i]- living.expensethisyear   
}
}
```

Comment: maybe `1e6 - cumsum(30e3*1.05^(0:49))`?

Comment: Without randomness, there's no need to `set.seed` or to repeat the simulation - you should get the same answer every time.